# «Представить её сидящей... и разбирающей бисер». Верно ли склонение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

**Только представить её сидящей на одном месте и разбирающей бисер – невозможно**.

Верно ли употребление «сидящей» или нужно сказать «сидящую... и разбирающую»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, в данной фразе склонение выбрано верно. Тире перед "невозможно" служит усилителем интонации, можно написать и без него.

---

А второй вариант должен выглядеть так: "Только представить её, сидящую на одном месте и разбирающую бисер, невозможно." Невозможно не потому, что она сидит и разбирает бисер, а по какой-то иной причине.

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно, постановка тире связана с инверсией наречия: **Только представить её сидящей на одном месте и разбирающей бисер – невозможно.**

Без инверсии: Только невозможно представить её сидящей на одном месте и разбирающей бисер.

**Выбор падежа**

**Сказуемое**: представить (какой?) сидящей и разбирающей (Т.п.).

При обособлении оборот относится к местоимению (В.п): представить её (какую?), сидящую и разбирающую.

Answer (score 0):

Только представить её сидящей на одном месте и разбирающей бисер – невозможно.

В этом случае указывается не только объект восприятия (она), но и характер этого восприятия (представить сидящей... и разбирающей...).

Только представить её, сидящую на одном месте и разбирающую бисер, – невозможно.

Здесь только определение предмета при помощи обособленного причастного оборота.